# Panning with cocos2d-x

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, cocos2d-x

Is there any way with cocos2d-x to emulate a pan action like you can do with the UIGestureRecognizer? I originally wrote my app in cocos2d-iphone and it is working using UIGestureRecognizer but I cannot find an approach for doing panning using C++ to work across multiple platforms. I am currently thinking about making native calls to both Android and iOS platforms using the NDK Helper but I think this will be complicated so I would like to check for other approaches first

Thanks

Comment: Did you try CCTouches method like CCTouchesBegin ? Using them you can make your own Gesture recognizers.

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of the Gesture Recognizer extensions and if they'd help in your case. But do check them out here [Gesture Recognizers](https://github.com/spalx/cocos2d-x-extensions/tree/master/CCGestureRecognizer)

Comment: Thanks @uchamp. I was not aware of the extension so I will give that a try first before going down the path of writing it myself